Porque se combinan las celdas en el documento RDLC?

Buen día, me encuentro trabajando con la herramienta RDLC para convertir el documento en Excel, al realizar esto el reporte se genera con las columnas combinadas, cosa que como se ve en la imagen esta ajustada para que esto no pase.
Existe algún ajuste dentro de RDLC en Visual Studio para que esto se ajuste de manera automática?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
